# an application of Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a subspace of $L^1(\mu)$. Construct a bounded linear functional on $M$ such that there are two (hence infinite) different linear extensions preserving norm to $L^1(\mu)$.

Someone outlined me as follows: pick $\tilde{f}$ on $\bar{M}$ (the closure of $M$) such that $\tilde{f}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ such that $\parallel \tilde{f}\parallel_1=\parallel f_n\parallel_1$, where $f_n$ are bounded linear functional defined on $M$, then put $F(x)=\frac{n}{n+1}\tilde{f}(x)$.

But I have some questions about it :

(1) does an extension be in accordance with a functional or several functionals?

(2) Why should we define an functional $\tilde{f}$ on $\bar{M}$ first? Or, can we define an extension just like this: $F(x)=\frac{n}{n+1}f(x)$ where $f$ is a bounded linear functional on $M$.

We have known, by the Hahn-Banach theorem,we can find such an $F$.

(3) There isn't requirement of $M$ being closed in the Hahn-Banach theorem, if $M$ is closed, can we get some special arguments or a simpler proof?

Maybe the three questions have something resembly, but I haven't find it explicitly. I need your kind help, please.